# Check contents of folder in Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to find out if `/opt/refresh_key.sh` exists in my docker container. I've tried the likes of `docker container inspect container_name` and also `docker run -it image_name sh` but neither seem to be what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Docker run` launch a new container. 
If you want to dive inside your existing container you should do:

`docker exec -it <container-name> /bin/bash`

and then you will have access to the filesystem of the existing container.

You can find container-name by doing `docker ps`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
docker exec -it <contailer-id> [[ -f "/bin/sh" ]] && echo "exists"
```

Place your file name in place of /bin/sh

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but got this response: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"[[\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`